# Random variables within for loop

Tags: java, random, for-loop, double, scope

I'm trying to draw 5 squares onto a Graphics2D instance.  Each of the 5 squares should have a random double value for both the top-left corner x-coordinate and the top-left corner y-coordinate.

```
double pixelSize = 2.0;

g2d.setColor(color);

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    double nextDouble = gen.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("nextDouble: "+nextDouble);
    double topLeftX = nextDouble*(maxX-minX) + minX;
    System.out.println("topLeftX: "+topLeftX);
    double topLeftY = nextDouble*(maxY-minY) + minY;
    System.out.println("topLeftY: "+topLeftY);

    Shape square = new Rectangle2D.Double(topLeftX, topLeftY, pixelSize, pixelSize);
    g2d.fill(square);
    repaint();
    revalidate();
}
```

Instead, what I see from the `println` statements, is that the `nextDouble` values are changing upon each iteration of the loop, but `topLeftX` and `topLeftY` stay the same, even though they're calculated partly from `nextDouble`.

I would like `topLeftX` and `topLeftY` to change each time through the loop.

Comment: What value you have in `maxX` & `minX`?

Comment: and also in `maxY` and `minY`

Comment: Whats your maxY and minY

Comment: I tried it with gen initialized as a java.util.Random, double minX = 10;
    double maxX = 20;
    double minY = 30;
    double maxY = 100; and the values did change. Maybe this is not the code that is really failing?

Comment: minX=394.0; maxX=395.0; minY=188.0; maxY=189.0

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are changing, but only in the digits after the decimal point, as one would expect given the code, and the unit differences in maxX-minX and maxY-minY:

```
nextDouble: 0.731057369148862
topLeftX: 394.73105736914886
topLeftY: 188.73105736914886
nextDouble: 0.07099203475193139
topLeftX: 394.07099203475195
topLeftY: 188.07099203475192
```

...